# "I am not going to buy your threats" and "who's going to buy your lies" can someone explain these two sentences to me

Tags: meaning

"I am not going to buy your threats" and "who's going to buy your lies"  can someone explain these two sentences to me

Comment: Please [edit] into your question the research you have already done, so answerers don't retread old ground.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an abbreviated form of "buy into" something. According to this source (https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/buy-into-something) it's genesis was the stock market, and it is still in use in that regard. See https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/buyin.asp. In American vernacular, it's used to indicate one is not inclined to believe the subject referred to has value, so they're not going to subscribe (Merrium-Webster: feel favorably disposed) to it. Simplified, if you saw it in the store, you wouldn't buy it. If you don't buy into something, you don't believe it. A similar idiom is "That doesn't hold water." It's like a pail with holes - worthless.